# Where is my Error?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

I have just have written this code I want it to merge two Arrays in one and sort it .. I have changed a lot of the code , I think my error is in the method array_intil()... but I can't find it...thanks all

```
public class Test3 {
    public int [] array_erz(int[]A1,int[]A2){
        int []neu=new int[A1.length+A2.length];
        return neu;
    }
    public void swap(int[]values,int i,int k){
        int temp;
        temp=values[i];
        values[i]=values[k];
        values[k]=temp;


    }
    public int [] array_intil(int [] neu,int[]A1,int []A2){
        for (int i=0;i<A1.length;i++){
            neu[i]=A1[i];
        for (int k=A1.length;k<neu.length;k++){
            neu[k]=A2[i];
        }}

        return neu;

    }
    public int[] sort(int[] neu){
        for (int i=0;i<neu.length;i++){
            for (int k=neu.length-1;k>i;k--){
                if (neu[i]>neu[k]){
                    swap(neu,i,k);
                }
            }
        }
        return neu;
    }
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int [] A1={7,0,12,738};
        int []A2={14,105,2,13,404,1,15,130};
        Test3 t=new Test3();
        int [] A3=t.array_erz(A1, A2);
        t.array_intil(A3, A1, A2);
        t.sort(A3);
        for (int i=0;i<A3.length;i++){
            System.out.print(A3[i]+",");
        }




    }

}
```

The result in the console is: 0,7,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,738,

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a nested loop adding A2 lots of times, try the following change:

```
public int [] array_intil(int [] neu,int[]A1,int []A2){
    for (int i=0;i<A1.length;i++){
        neu[i]=A1[i];
    }
    for (int k=A1.length;k<neu.length;k++){
        neu[k]=A2[k-A1.length];
    }

    return neu;

}
```

Also always keep your code well formatted with tabs, I almost missed the nested for loop cause they were indented the same!

Answer (score 0):

you are right there is problem in your array_intil method. In your program , the second for loop get executed for every iteration of first loop

modify your method as below:

```
 public int [] array_intil(int [] neu,int[]A1,int []A2){
       int i=0;
        for (i=0;i<A1.length;i++){
            neu[i]=A1[i];
        }
        int m=0;
        for (i=A1.length;i<neu.length;i++){
            neu[i]=A2[m];
            m++;
        }
        return neu;
    }

Now correct/modify your sorting/swapping algo.
```